# How do I Backup new website

Tags: admin, backup

I have a new website and I am new to Magento. Can someone tell me how to backup my information in admin. I just want to be sure that I don't loose everything and I unfortunately have no help from my developers. I had a look in admin and it doesn't look difficult but I am worried that I may delete everything. 
Thankyou 
website: www.glamoroushairstyles.com.au

Comment: I have just done a database backup in admin but I now want to do a manual backup. Can you tell me where do I find this in admin?

Comment: To back up, find phpMyAdmin in the hosting control panel and choose “export” from the menu bar. In many cases you can stick with the “Quick” option, but, if you have more than one database in the same MySQL install, for example, choose the “Custom” option and find the relevant database in the drop-down list. Unless you know what you’re doing, leave the other options alone. Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click “Go”. A dump of the database will be downloaded and you can store it with the files you downloaded earlier or somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

From: http://blog.nexcess.net/2013/08/08/backing-up-a-magento-ecommerce-site/

There are a number of options in the admin panel for backing up a Magento store. You can find them  in `System  >  Tool` admin menu. **There are three types of backup** to choose from:

**System Backup** — This will take all of the files that comprise the Magento store and a dump of the data and package them into a tar archive.

**Database and Media Backup** — This includes the database and the contents of the media folder, but not other assets like theme files.

**Database backup** — This does what you’d expect.

One benefit of backing up this way is that Magento allows roll-backs to previous backups, which means that if you make a configuration error or accidentally delete files you can restore the system to its earlier state.

In some cases you’ll want to back up the database and the files separately, and it’s also useful to know how to do a manual backup, so we’ll run through the process of backing up outside of the Magento admin panel.

Comment: I have just done a database backup in admin but I now want to do a manual backup. Can you tell me where do I find this in admin?

Comment: To back up, find phpMyAdmin in the hosting control panel and choose “export” from the menu bar. In many cases you can stick with the “Quick” option, but, if you have more than one database in the same MySQL install, for example, choose the “Custom” option and find the relevant database in the drop-down list. Unless you know what you’re doing, leave the other options alone.

Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click “Go”. A dump of the database will be downloaded and you can store it with the files you downloaded earlier or somewhere else.